# ngOnInit called again on router.navigate before unloading the page in Angular 15

Tags: angular

I have one issue. From the edit component, when I route back to the home page, I notice the edit page's `ngOnInit()` is being called again before unloading/destroying the component. How I can prevent it? Any suggestions? This is how I am redirecting:

```js
this.router.navigate(['../../'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

Comment: The [Angular lifecycle hooks docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence) say that `ngOnInit()` is "Called once, after the first `ngOnChanges()`.". Is it possible you either have code calling `ngOnInit()` manually or that you're destroying and re-instantiating the component from a parent somewhere?

Comment: The framework having a bug is very unlikely in this case since it would be a very visible issue. I don't see an issue for it [on the GitHub issues board for Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+ngoninit) but feel free to check for one yourself. Could you please try and include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your code so the community can replicate the issue?

Comment: @DM I have found the solution. Thank you. I will update the answer